# How many edges can a $G$ free graph have for a given $G$?

Tags: combinatorics

I am looking for what is known about a generelization of Turans theorem that gives information regarding the number of edges a $G$-free graph (a graph that does not contain $G$ as an induced graph (meaning you can't delete vertices,edges from your graph and get $G$).

I am aware that there are some results regarding with what probablity $G$ appears in $(G,1/2)$, that in particular give a lower bound, but I'm also very interested in an upper bound.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read this pdf
https://www.dpmms.cam.ac.uk/~dc340/EGT3.pdf

This exactly answers your question.